# Given $l(f)$ a linear operator, show that it integrates all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ exactly.

Tags: integration, interpolation-theory

Given $l(f)$ a linear operator, if  $l(F)$ integrates  $1,x,...,x^n$ exactly, show that it integrates all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ exactly.

How would I even go about this? I was shown this proof as a takeaway in lecture and I have absolutely no idea on how to even start it?

Comment: I would start with the fact that $l$ is a *linear* operator, the fact that every polynomial of degree no more than $n$ can be written as a *linear* combination of $1,\ldots, x^n$, and the definition of "integrates."

Comment: a linear combination of the monomials 1, x, x2, ..., xn.
To integrate each monomial exactly over [a, b] use the Newton-Cotes quadrature.

Comment: @Neal I think I may be completely off but cant we just say that since l(F) integrates all polynomials from 1,..,x^n we can express our polynomial as a combination of integrals since all polynomials can be expressed as a combination of the integration of the set of basis. I feel like this is a bit too simplistic of an answer for a numerical integration section

Comment: But it's the right idea. Just formalize it; actually write out a generic polynomial polynomial, what $l$ does to it using the fact that $l$ is linear, etc.

Comment: @user126885 "I feel like this is a bit too simplistic of an answer" ... don't! You know enough to say whether it answers the question -- never think too hard. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean by 'integrates exactly', lets suppose
it means that if $I(p) = \int_a^b p(x) dx$ for some $a,b$.

Then
$l(f) = I(f)$ for the functions $x \mapsto x^k$, $k=0,..,n$.

Since $l$ and $I$ are linear it follows that
$l(x \mapsto \sum_k a_k x^k) = \sum_k a_kl ( x \mapsto  x^k ) = \sum_k a_k I ( x \mapsto  x^k ) = I(x \mapsto \sum_k a_k x^k)$.